# Data Tables inside of a Modal

Tags: abp

Does anyone know how to get datatables to work inside of a modal? I've been following the example at https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Modals#modals-with-script-files and bascially did all of my work to load the datatable inside the initModal function but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check **CmsKit.Admin.Web** project for view the usage of modal in datatable.

1-) Create your modal view. (.cshtml file):

[Volo.CmsKit.Admin.Web/Pages/CmsKit/Blogs/CreateModal.cshtml](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/48c52625f4c4df007f04d5ac6368b07411aa7521/modules/cms-kit/src/Volo.CmsKit.Admin.Web/Pages/CmsKit/Blogs/CreateModal.cshtml#L15-L23)

2-) Define your `abp.modals` class. (.js file for your modal):

[Volo.CmsKit.Admin.Web/Pages/CmsKit/Blogs/createModal.js](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/48c52625f4c4df007f04d5ac6368b07411aa7521/modules/cms-kit/src/Volo.CmsKit.Admin.Web/Pages/CmsKit/Blogs/createModal.js#L3-L46)

3-) Define your modal by using `ModalManager` and call the modal wherever its needed:

- [Define Modal Manager](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/48c52625f4c4df007f04d5ac6368b07411aa7521/modules/cms-kit/src/Volo.CmsKit.Admin.Web/Pages/CmsKit/Blogs/index.js#L5)
- [Open the modal when an event triggered](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/48c52625f4c4df007f04d5ac6368b07411aa7521/modules/cms-kit/src/Volo.CmsKit.Admin.Web/Pages/CmsKit/Blogs/index.js#L73-L76)

  - You can create a row action and open the modal when the action is clicked.

```js
...

rowAction: {
   items: [
             {
                text: l('MyRowAction'),
                action: function (data) {
                   myModal.open();
                }
             },
          ]
}
...
```

- [Refresh the datatable according to the changes of your modal](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/48c52625f4c4df007f04d5ac6368b07411aa7521/modules/cms-kit/src/Volo.CmsKit.Admin.Web/Pages/CmsKit/Blogs/index.js#L78-L80)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out on my own.  I tried to specify my class as an object (no quotes) rather than a string as in their example:

```
var productInfoModal = new abp.ModalManager({
    viewUrl: '/Products/ProductInfoModal',
    scriptUrl: '/Pages/Products/ProductInfoModal.js', //Lazy Load URL
    modalClass: 'ProductInfo' // << Make sure to specify as a string
});
```